# Retrieve 1st item ID for Active Accordion tab in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion with some list items inside (code below). Is there any way to find out the 1st item data-id of the active accordion tab. For example., on page load, the active tab is Temperature Gauge which is the 2nd tab. Now I want to retrieve the 1st option data-id which is 11.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function ()
   { 
      $("#accordion").accordion(
      {
        activate: function(event, ui)
        {
            var activeTab = $(this).accordion( "option", "active" );
            alert(activeTab);

            var intID = $('.SubCatFakeClass').attr("data-id");
            alert(intID);

        }
      });

   });
</script>

<div id="accordion">

<h3 class="">Pressure Gauge</h3>

    <div>
        <ul class="ulStyle">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-id="2" class="SubCatFakeClass">Pressure Gauge</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-id="3" class="SubCatFakeClass">Diff. Pressure Gauge</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-id="10" class="SubCatFakeClass">Diaphragm Seal</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<h3 class="">Temperature Gauge</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="ulStyle">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-id="11" class="SubCatFakeClass">Temperature Gauge</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-id="13" class="SubCatFakeClass">Thermowell</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<h3 class="">Switch</h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="ulStyle">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-id="14" class="SubCatFakeClass">Pressure Switch</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-id="18" class="SubCatFakeClass">Temperature Switch</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to get the nth div:

```
var intID = $(this).children("div:eq(" + activeTab + ")")
                   .find('.SubCatFakeClass')
                   .attr("data-id");
```

You could use `.find('.SubCatFakeClass:first-child')`, but `.attr` will return the result of the first one regardless.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vj7vd0zz/)

Answer (score 1):

**To get active tab:**

```
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" ); //get active tab
```

**To get first li data ID:**

```
$(active).find('.SubCatFakeClass:eq(0)').data('id');
```

or

```
$(active).find('li:eq(0)').data('id');
```

Comment: says undefined. Can you please tell me what is `.active` is it the active tab

Comment: @YashmanGupta: that is the active class added to accordion. have you ensured that you are getting the data on document ready.

Comment: understood but it is returning `undefined` instead of ID